# Android why background image extends scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

Hello I have a scrollview and relative layout inside it.

When I decline background for scrollview, scrollview extends height of background image.

When I run the application, I see that activity can scroll to bottom and there is no item at this area.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:background="@drawable/back2"
android:padding="0dp" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:padding="0dp"
 >
```

Comment: Post the complete code of xml ! .. So that its clear for developers to solve  it !

Comment: ScrollView is scrollable it will be sure extend at bottom as per background image. Show your screen shot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in RelativeLayout height. You can't set relativeLayout height to match parent, when you put it inside scrollView. ScrollView don't have exact inner height, so your relative layout can't measure their height. It's mean that in your case your RelativeLayout may have any height even it's empty. It could be 2 screens for example or have infinitive height (infinitive scroll would be in this case).
It's undefined behavior and you can't wait any exact height in this case. You can put element with layout_height="match_parent" only inside layout which have defined height.

Answer (score 1):

1) does it get better if you specify background for RelativeLayout instead of ScrollView?

2) You can do the following construct:

```
<FrameView ...>
    <View background=anything *OR* ImageView src=anything ... />
    <ScrollView ...>
        <RelativeLayout background=transparentColor ...>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameView>
```

FrameView draws its children one on top of another, the first child is the background and
the 2nd child is what you do now.

Answer (score 1):

**Why scrollview is extending**:: ***`You might be using high resolution(large) image causing it to extend as you have explained in your question`***

**Possible solution**::***`Instead of background image, put the color to the background of scrollview`***

---

**Test**::

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#FE2EC8"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:padding="0dp"
     >
```